# React native reset Drawer Items - react navigation nested stack navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

My route structure is as Follows

```
- StackNavigator
  -- SplaceScreen
  -- LoginScreen
  -- HomeScreen (Drawer Navigator)
    --- Listing Screen (Stack Navigator)(Default Screen that loads)
    --- Booking Screen (Stack Navigator)
    --- Profile Screen (Stack Navigator)
```

**Expected Behaviour**

Now when i navigate to Booking screen From Listing screen, I want to replace Listing screen with Booking Screen (e.i when i press back on Android I dont want to see Listing screen)

**Current Behaviour**

Booking screen is adding above Listing screen (e.i it is not replacing)

**Solution Tried**

```
 const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                key:null,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'BookingScreen' })],
            });
            props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

**Error Received**

*There is no route defined for Key BookingScreen. Must be one of 'SplashScreen,LoginScreen,HomeScreen'*

So how to reset inner stack

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` will replace the current route in the stack:

```
 StackActions.replace('BookingScreen')
```

you will not be able to back to the replaced route.